# Where was Nightcrawler during Infinity Crusade?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, continuity

In the *Infinity Crusade* (1993) limited series, heroes are separated into two groups - those who have some type of religious belief, and those who don't (to put it simply). There are scenes of lots of different groups being sorted this way, the X-Men included. However, Kurt Wagner is nowhere to be seen. I would have expected him to be an obvious choice for a story like this.

So where was he?

Comment: There was a really long line at the confessional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Infinity Crusade](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Crusade_Vol_1)* was published during the latter half of 1993. From 1988 to 1998, Nightcrawler was a member of the team, [Excalibur](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Excalibur_(Earth-616)), who were based in Captain Britain and Psylocke's ancestral home, [Braddock Manor](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Braddock_Manor), in the UK.

In *[Infinity Crusade #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Crusade_Vol_1_1)*, Professor X (Charles Xavier) indicated that Excalibur were unable to be contacted at the time.

> PROFESSOR X: We haven't been able to contact either Excalibur or X-Force.
>
> HULK: And you say that Quasar is off the planet?
>
> IRON MAN: Completely out of touch.
>
> GUARDIAN: What about the group called the Infinity Watch?
>
> HAVOK: We don't know how to contact them.
>
> [image: Infinity Crusade #1, page 30.]
>
> <sub>*Infinity Crusade #1* (June, 1993)</sub>

*Infinity Crusade #1* was published in the same month (June 1993) as *[Excalibur Vol. 1 #66](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Excalibur_Vol_1_66)*, in which Excalibur were transported to the alternate future of [Earth-811](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-811), the setting of the "[Days of Future Past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_of_Future_Past)" storyline from *[X-Men Vol. 1 #141](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_141)*-*[142](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_142)* and the native timeline of [Rachel Summers](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Rachel_Summers_(Earth-811)).

> SHADOWCAT: Can you help us find Rachel and Widget?
>
> TANGERINE: I'm afraid that's impossible. They were teleported straight to Sentinel H.Q.
>
> SHADOWCAT: Where is it? How do we get there?
>
> ARTHUR: You'd have to be insane to go. The Sentinels dominate this Earth. There are millions of them. Each learning from the others' experience. Each capable of adapting to overcome any foe.
>
> NIGHTCRAWLER: We have encountered the Sentinels before.
>
> TANGERINE: Then you must know that your friends are lost.
>
> NIGHTCRAWLER: Not while hope endures. But even if they are, we have not the power to return home. We are stranded, so our choice is simple. We either defeat the Sentinels... or die trying.
>
> [image: Excalibur Vol. 1 #66, page 22.]
>
> <sub>*Excalibur Vol. 1 #66* (June, 1993)</sub>

Excalibur remained on Earth-811 until the end of *[Excalibur Vol. 1 #67](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Excalibur_Vol_1_67)*, and while I'm unaware of any direct confirmation that this is where they were during the events of *Infinity Crusade*, it seems the most logical explanation for why Xavier was unable to contact them.